# MySQL Server Status CPU/Load Formula

Tags: mysql

Are there any variables and formula that can help me calculate CPU/Load value of MySQL ?

Comment: Trial by testing is the usual way. What do you have currently? What version? What hardware? How is the application behaving? Memory and IO speed/IOs are just as important.

Comment: The OS is better at that.  There are no `GLOBAL STATUS` values that even come close.  There are a lot of values that give specific clues into the "server status", but not CPU or Load-average.  Examples: cache usage (there are several caches); I/O (but rather raw, as in bytes or blocks); connections.

Comment: Lay out your cards (GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES), and I will read your fortune.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [sysstat](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat) (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysstat)) and/or [nmon](http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php) - great free tools! Among the sysstat tools are [`iostat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iostat) and [`mpstat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpstat) (check the link). There's also [`top`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_(software)) - you could look at that also! The pidstat (no separate wiki entry - see sysstat) might be right up your alley - I would urge you to explore the man pages!

What you want are baselines so that when things start to go wrong, you know:

- what has been happening over the last minute, hour, day, week, month, year...?
- what's happening now - is your I/O swamped, or is it your CPU or your RAM? Also, [the network](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-network-bandwidth-monitoring-tools/) should be under surveillance!
- what's happened when you changed parameter X or cancelled report Y

You should be [saving the output](https://www.tecmint.com/save-top-command-output-to-a-file/). The example is for `top`, but you should be keeping **all** of your monitoring stats so that you can graph it and trace problems when they occur. Ideally, I would be putting the output into a database - MySQL in your case. For example, [`sar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sar_(Unix)) (System Activity Report) is the sysstat tool for commands:

> used to report on various system loads, including CPU activity,
> memory/paging, interrupts, device load, network and swap space
> utilization

Even though sysstat isn't part of the Linux kernel proper, I would consider it an "honourary kernel module".

Normally, tool recommendations are off-topic here, but these tools have been around since forever and are unlikely to disappear anytime soon. If these don't suit you, a quick internet search will reveal many more - you really are spoilt for choice when it comes to (impressive) F/LOSS monitoring tools!

Answer (score 0):

From your MySQL root login when at the command prompt,

```
status;
```

will include the last 2 lines with many valuable pieces of information.  Example follows -

Uptime:                 10 days 8 hours 45 min 36 sec

Threads: 7  Questions: 61  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 18  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 12  Queries per second avg: 0.000